# access static parametr of class in static paramter of a different class

Tags: php, oop, static

I'm trying to access a static paramter of a class, witch instance is stored in a static paramter of another class.
This is how it looks like.

```
parent::$model = new $model(); 
parent::$model::$lang = $lang_id;
```

php is respoding with "unexpected '::'" on the line where I'm trying to store $lang_id.
Please tell, if this is even posiible in php and eventually how do I do it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dunno if I understood this correctly, but `model::$lang = $lang_id` maybe? Assuming that `model` is a class and `lang` is a property of that class.

Comment: Oh, my bad :D it's so obvious, but I'm still just a beginner. Thank you for quick response.

Comment: @Andrew The notation for static properties is still `$foo::$bar`. `::BAR` is for constants only.

Comment: @Adam You should really not get used to `static` too much. Learn OOP with instances and parameters, not ["static classes"](http://kunststube.net/static).

Comment: I'm using it just in this case, to remember current language id across all models, that's all. But thanks for advice. Btw. what's bad on "static" ?